# How do we know that var declarations are hoisted?

Tags: javascript

We all know that code like this

```js
'use strict'

a = 5;

var a;
```

would first declare the variable `a` and then assign a value to it, but is there a way to see how this code is transformed in such a way that declaration goes first?

I checked AST explorer and it doesn't show what I want to see (it shows `ExpressionStatement` first, and only then `VariableDeclaration` goes), and bytecode doesn't show it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the actual hoisting happens after building the AST, and there is no other way to "see" it than checking V8 source code.